NavigationLink with & without NavigationDestination
I am in the process of learning Swift, coming from years of PowerShell on Windows, and as I am digging into NavigationStack I am seeing some patterns but I don't understand what is going on under the hood.
If all I want to use is the default navigation in the toolbar, I can use NavigationLinks without NavigationDestinations and the < PreviousTitle in the upper left works just fine. But if I want to have my own button to do something like return to root, then I must use a NavigationDestination as well. Both cases I have a NavigationRouter class that provides a path for the environment.
So, what is the NavigationDestination doing differently under the hood that enables my custom navigation? And are there any other situations where this becomes an issue. Indeed, is the fact that I CAN forgo NavigationDestinations in some cases a code smell, and I really should just avoid it? I mean beyond the fact that if I decide later I do need more than the default navigation I will need to refactor.
On a somewhat tangential note, I am also trying to have a link that just goes to a very simple view that needs no arguments. For example an info page. As far as I can tell there is no such thing as a NavigationDestination that is NOT tied to a type in some way. What I have come up with is to use Bool as my type, so
NavigationLink("info",value: true)
.navigationDestination(for:  Bool.self) { bool in
    TextView()
}

I find this slightly less offensive than a String type where I pass a string that is just thrown away, but it is still a meaningless true, it works just as well with false, which to me is not great for understandability later. I feel like a view like this is probably pretty edge case, I can just use a sheet or something and leave the navigation to more data driven views, but I do wonder if there is a more elegant navigation based answer? Or is navigation purely data driven?
